# multiple pull requests from the same branch

Tags: git, git-branch, pull-request

Say I have 3 branches: `master`, `release` and `myfeature`. Is it possible to create 2 pull requests from `myfeature` to both `master` and `release` without creating another branch?

Why might I want this?

Say master is the current latest, and release was a year ago. When a bug is fixed a PR is created against release, now this fix also needs to go into master, a cherry pick is perfect, but that will need a new branch as far as I know. I just wish it was possible to use the same original fix branch to merge into both (as long as master is still compatible).

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to think a little more about your branches, and why you have them.

There's nothing to stop you from creating pull requests between your branches. I assume you're creating pull requests so that you can have conversations about those changes. I guess my question is "how will the conversation be different in these two cases?"

It feels, to me, like you may want to use a PR to have a conversation as you merge changes from `myfeature` to `master`, but once that conversation has happened the merge from `master` to `release` doesn't need to occur...it's just a merge.

I wonder if you should be using tags, rather than branches, in place of `release`. You may also want to check out some of the following resources to define how you're going to use git to manage this sort of thing:

[GitHub's docs on Pull Requests](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/)

[Altasian's view on git workflows](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows)

[The original post on git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: git-flow would resolve this issue. The my-feature bug-resolving branch should be branched from release, merged back in release with the fix, the the master should be merged back in master, resolving eventual conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

in all likelihood, master would have evolved from release branch forcing you to have different implementation/fixes for both of them. 
Hence **Cherry-Picking** is the most widely recommended way to proceed here.

If not as is your case,

1. get the PR for release branch merged first
2. rebase to master and create another pull request